# Класс актив для меню и сайт бара

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать автоматическое подсвечивание пункта меню и сайт-бара на сайте, что бы он определял на какой стр пользователь и выделял этот пункт меню. в `html` адрес страницы указан `page/page.html` на хостинге `page/page (.html)` убирается.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.list__item {
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.current {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">Пункт 1</li>
  <li class="list__item">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="list__item current">Пункт 3</li>
  <li class="list__item">Пункт 4</li>
  <li class="list__item">Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```